# Detect if an <li> is overflowed in a horizontal single row <ul> list

Tags: jquery, css

My `<ul>` list is a horizontal menu list. It is a single row. It has lot of `<li>` elements. So I want to detect if an `<li>` item overflowed and displaying in the second row. So that i can add them into another `<ul>` list and display inside of the last `<li>` tag which says "more".

Is there a way to do this? So that user can't see overflowed items are loaded and hide. Instead user will see a "more" element at the most right of the menu and when he decreasing window width, each last `<li>` will be added to that set of "more" smoothly.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to create codepen for this? Might be a bit easier to exactly identify what you are after. Cheers

Comment: @Carlton Sure, i just created a pen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOBaRy I want to add that all the second row links into `more > ul`.